# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'cliente_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo las siguientes relaciones:

```
 cliente-> factura, 
factura->detalle,
materiaPrima->detalle
```

Como seria la manera mas practica de realizar el ingreso de la factura, ya que no creo que 1 solo boton pueda realizar varias acciones, de tal forma necesito separar en 2 partes la vista, la primera que me tome el dato de la factura y luego del cliente,
El orden que asumo para crear el registro de dicha factura es primero crear la factura tomando el id del cliente, pero me lanza este error, no se si tengo mal la relacion, o no se como enviar ese dato realmente. estos son los modelos y el controlador que se encarga de hacer el guardar, me gustaria si con 1 solo formulario podria realizar el ingreso de todo en esta relacion, pero soy nuevo manejando laravel realmente.

LOS MODELOS

```
    class Cliente extends Model
{
    protected $table = "Cliente";
    protected $fillable = ['nombre', 'documento','direccion','ciudad','telefono', 'email'];

    public function facturas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(factura::class);
    }
}



class Factura extends Model
{
    protected $table = "Factura";
    protected $fillable = ['num_factura','fecha'];

    public function materiasPrimas()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(MateriaPrima::class, 'detalle','factura_id','materiaPrima_id')->withPivot('precio','cantidad');
    }

    public function cliente()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Cliente::class);
    }
}


class MateriaPrima extends Model
{
    protected $table = "MateriaPrima";
    protected $fillable = ['codigo', 'nombre', 'unit','precio_in','cantidad', 'foto'];

public function facturas()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Factura::class, 'detalle','materiaPrima_id','factura_id')->withPivot('precio','cantidad');
    }
```

AHORA EN ESTE CONTROLLADOR ENVIO LOS DATOS DE TODOS LOS CLIENTES

```
public function crear()
    {
        can('crear-Factura');
        $cliente = Cliente::orderBy('id')->pluck('nombre', 'id')->toArray();
        return view('Factura.crear',compact('cliente'));
    }


public function guardar(Request $request)
    {
        $factura=Factura::create($request->all());
        $factura->cliente()->sync($request->cliente_id);
        return redirect()->route('Factura')->with('mensaje', 'El registro se creo correctamente');
    }
```

este es el formulario que esta tomando los datos:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="num_factura" class="col-lg-3 col-form-label requerido">Numero de Factura </label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
    <input type="text" name="num_factura" id="num_factura" class="form-control" value="{{old('num_factura', $data->num_factura ?? '')}}" required/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="fecha" class="col-lg-3 col-form-label requerido">Fecha</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
    <input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha" class="form-control" value="{{old('fecha', $data->fecha ?? '')}}" required/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="form-group row">
     <label for="cliente_id" class="col-lg-3 col-form-label requerido">Seleccione Proveedor</label>
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <select name="cliente_id[]" id="cliente_id" class="form-control" multiple required>
@foreach($cliente as $id => $nombre)
  <option
  value="{{$id}}"
  {{is_array(old('cliente_id')) ? (in_array($id, old('cliente_id')) ? 'selected' : '')  : (isset($data) ? ($data->cliente->firstWhere('id', $id) ? 'selected' : '') : '')}}
  >
  {{$nombre}}
  </option>
@endforeach
</select>
</div> 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: 2 preguntas: si el método `sync` puede recibir 1 o N cantidad de ids para hacer eso la sincronización, yo no veo correcto que: `$factura` sea el request completo de valores que pases, es decir de ese request deberías pasar solo el atributo id, por otro lado ¿seguro que `$request->cliente_id` si trae algún valor?

Comment: Efectivamente, ese request cliente, me trae el option seleccionado en la vista como id ya lo comprobe con el dd